# addProximityAlert fired only with the last location

Tags: android, geolocation, android-intent

I'm using next function to set proximityAlerts:

```
public void addProximityAlerts(double latitude, double longitude, double radius) 
    {
        try{
            //Prepare proximity Intent
            proximityIntent = new Intent(activityContext.getString(R.string.intent_message_location_fetched));
            proximityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activityContext, 0, proximityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, (float) radius, -1, proximityPendingIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
            SendHandle(LOCATION_ADDING_ALERTS_FAILED);


}
}
```

And call this:

```
location.addProximityAlerts(33.3333, 33.3333, 1000);
location.addProximityAlerts(12, 12, 5000);
location.addProximityAlerts(42, 42, 5000);
```

But Intent fired only when I'm around 42, 42 - the last used location. 
What's wrong? Shouldn't alerts work with all given points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action must be unique!
Thank [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298388/set-2-proximity-alerts-with-the-same-broadcast/3298625#3298625)

Now I'm creating receiver in the addProximityAlerts finction using

```
getString(R.string.intent_message_location_fetched)+latitude+longitude
```

as unique action